# Use GenerateTableFetch processor for Teradata

Tags: teradata, apache-nifi

We need to use GenerateTableFetch to fetch huge data from teradata using nifi. But since Teradata is not present as a database type it generate Limit keyword. I am able to replace it with Sample keyword. But sample everytime give random value so how can i use Nifi with Teradata for huge table?

Comment: You might try `SELECT TOP n` instead of `LIMIT n`.

Comment: but generateTableFetch creates a range of query with page size, so if page size is 100. the first query will fetch 0-100 and second will fetch 100-200, third 200-300. How to run such a query which fetches like rownum in teradata?

Comment: Without an `order by` you can't reliably get the same order in your result set. Using `row_number` over unique column(s) will work, but this might be a huge overhead for

Comment: I think you can [use the teradata JDBC drivers with nifi](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/45427/using-teradata-jdbc-connector-in-nifi.html).  I haven't actually done this, but it's on the list...

Comment: Hi Andrew,
We are using the same driver but the issue is we have to use generateTableFetch for large table and NIFI dont have a Implicit TeradataAdapter. So we are using MSSQL but those queries are not exactly in teradata format so we are using another script to format them for now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try the "MS SQL 2008" adapter, it generates a TOP statement as well as a ROW_NUMBER() OVER clause. If that doesn't work, we'd need a TeradataDatabaseAdapter implementation, please feel free to file an improvement Jira as needed.

Comment: I tried this is the query it generated :
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 10000 *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  asc) rnum FROM dbcinfo WHERE 1=1) A WHERE rnum > 0 AND rnum <= 10000

I know this query wont execute as it is but is there any way to modify it a bit and get it to run?

Comment: If you can identify the parts to change via regular expressions, then you can use ReplaceText for this.

Comment: Yeah did that only...have raised a JIRA also for generic implementation.